# Expressjs: Populate html tags not using jade

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I am currently developing blog app using node.js expressjs and learned how to display data from database into view(.jade):

```
// index.js
exports.userlist = function(db){
    return function(req, res) {
        var collection = db.get('usercollection');
        collection.find({},{},function(e, docs){
            res.render('userlist',{"userlist":docs});
        });
    };
};
```

and here's `userlist.jade`

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username
```

However, I have already the complete html pages and it will be a big burden to me converting them into .jade. Can someone help me on how to display data(like the looping of `<a href=""></a>`) but using .html? For example, with the codes given above, how can i implement it if my userlist.jade is actually userlist.html and html tags is what inside of it.

Comment: You can use another template engine like ejs, handlebars, etc... You can also use custom extensions for those template engines. I am using express3-handlebars, https://npmjs.org/package/express3-handlebars. Default extension is hbs, but I am using as .html

Comment: Yes, those templating engines are just HTML with some additions for the dynamic content. See http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/how-to-use-alternative-non-jade-template-engines-with-express/

Comment: @orvyl did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like Jade you don't have to give it up just because you have existing HTML pages. There are HTML to Jade converters out there, such as [this one](http://html2jade.com/).

That said, you can also use view engines that more closely resemble HTML such as [ejs](https://npmjs.org/package/express-ejs-layouts).